# why httpd reports less active modules than apachectl?

Tags: apache-httpd, ssl, nss

I am trying to enable mod-nss module in Apache2. So after doing what is necessary, I am trying to validate that indeed the module is loaded.

Asking apachectl

```
# apachectl -M | grep nss
 nss_module (shared)
```

Asking the daemon itself:

```
/usr/sbin/httpd-prefork -M | grep nss
-> No output
```

So, I get two different outputs:

- apachectl claims that the mod_nss module is loaded.
- httpd claims that the mod_nss module is not loaded.

After this, I decided to list the modules for both (instead of just grep-ing for a specific one), sort the output and then compare them.

```
# diff -Nur httpd_sorted_modules apachectl_sorted_modules 
--- httpd_sorted_modules        2016-09-01 13:59:16.297139860 +0200
+++ apachectl_sorted_modules    2016-09-01 13:59:26.680985223 +0200
@@ -15,11 +15,15 @@
  expires_module (shared)
  http_module (static)
  include_module (shared)
+ info_module (shared)
  log_config_module (shared)
  mime_module (shared)
  mpm_prefork_module (static)
  negotiation_module (shared)
+ nss_module (shared)
+ php5_module (shared)
  reqtimeout_module (shared)
+ rewrite_module (shared)
  setenvif_module (shared)
  so_module (static)
  socache_shmcb_module (shared)
```

As you can see, apachectl shows 4 extra modules in contrast to httpd. Why is that happening? And which one should I put my trust on?

I tried to see what's the difference between those, but I failed. Here's some of my findings:

apachectl seems to be a standalone binary

```
# ls -l `which apachectl`
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 3548 Aug 23 13:11 /usr/sbin/apachectl
```

that comes from apache pkg:

```
# rpm -qf `which apachectl`
apache2-2.4.16-12.1.x86_64
```

which is actually used to ease the control around httpd. Apparently, there is difference in using it with SystemD or SySVinit. Here's a quote from the man apachectl page:

> When acting in pass-through mode, apachectl can take all the arguments
>   available for the httpd binary.
>
> ```
>    apachectl [ httpd-argument ]
> ```
>
> When acting in SysV init mode, apachectl takes simple, one-word
>   commands, defined below.
>
> ```
>    apachectl command
> ```

So, if I request for the -h help option:

```
 # apachectl -h
Usage: /usr/sbin/httpd-prefork [-D name] [-d directory] [-f file]
                               [-C "directive"] [-c "directive"]
                               [-k start|restart|graceful|graceful-stop|stop]
                               [-v] [-V] [-h] [-l] [-L] [-t] [-T] [-S] [-X]
Options:
  -D name            : define a name for use in <IfDefine name> directives
  -d directory       : specify an alternate initial ServerRoot
  -f file            : specify an alternate ServerConfigFile
  -C "directive"     : process directive before reading config files
  -c "directive"     : process directive after reading config files
  -e level           : show startup errors of level (see LogLevel)
  -E file            : log startup errors to file
  -v                 : show version number
  -V                 : show compile settings
  -h                 : list available command line options (this page)
  -l                 : list compiled in modules
  -L                 : list available configuration directives
  -t -D DUMP_VHOSTS  : show parsed vhost settings
  -t -D DUMP_RUN_CFG : show parsed run settings
  -S                 : a synonym for -t -D DUMP_VHOSTS -D DUMP_RUN_CFG
  -t -D DUMP_MODULES : show all loaded modules 
  -M                 : a synonym for -t -D DUMP_MODULES
  -t                 : run syntax check for config files
  -T                 : start without DocumentRoot(s) check
  -X                 : debug mode (only one worker, do not detach)
```

So it seems that it's using the `/usr/sbin/httpd-prefork` or at least that what it says.

But let's try to see what 'httpd' is using in the background:

```
# which httpd
/usr/sbin/httpd
```

which seems to be a symlink:

```
# ls -l `which httpd`
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 23 Aug 25 13:28 /usr/sbin/httpd -> /usr/sbin/httpd-prefork
```

so it uses the `/usr/sbin/httpd-prefork` which is the same one with what apachectl seems to use. For example if I request for -h help, I get:

```
# /usr/sbin/httpd-prefork -h
Usage: /usr/sbin/httpd-prefork [-D name] [-d directory] [-f file]
                               [-C "directive"] [-c "directive"]
                               [-k start|restart|graceful|graceful-stop|stop]
                               [-v] [-V] [-h] [-l] [-L] [-t] [-T] [-S] [-X]
Options:
  -D name            : define a name for use in <IfDefine name> directives
  -d directory       : specify an alternate initial ServerRoot
  -f file            : specify an alternate ServerConfigFile
  -C "directive"     : process directive before reading config files
  -c "directive"     : process directive after reading config files
  -e level           : show startup errors of level (see LogLevel)
  -E file            : log startup errors to file
  -v                 : show version number
  -V                 : show compile settings
  -h                 : list available command line options (this page)
  -l                 : list compiled in modules
  -L                 : list available configuration directives
  -t -D DUMP_VHOSTS  : show parsed vhost settings
  -t -D DUMP_RUN_CFG : show parsed run settings
  -S                 : a synonym for -t -D DUMP_VHOSTS -D DUMP_RUN_CFG
  -t -D DUMP_MODULES : show all loaded modules 
  -M                 : a synonym for -t -D DUMP_MODULES
  -t                 : run syntax check for config files
  -T                 : start without DocumentRoot(s) check
  -X                 : debug mode (only one worker, do not detach)
```

which is identical to what I get with `apachectl -h`.

However, this one comes from another package:

```
# rpm -qf /usr/sbin/httpd-prefork
apache2-prefork-2.4.16-12.1.x86_64
```

Apart from that, I cannot think of a reason why I get different output when I query for the loaded modules :/

For those who would like to know, I am using OpenSUSE Leap 42.1 as my Linux distribution, and I run Apache with Prefork MPM.

Answer (score 0):

Given your listing:

```
# ls -l `which apachectl`
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 3548 Aug 23 13:11 /usr/sbin/apachectl
```

it is unlikely that your `apachectl` is a "standalone binary" (it is far too small: a plausible binary would be 10-20 times larger).  In fact, it is a shell script.  When you execute

```
apachectl -M
```

the shell script first obtains additional parameters from its configuration files, and puts those before the `-M` when executing the httpd binary.

For the purpose of discussion, I'll refer to the [git mirror of Apache](https://github.com/apache/httpd), and the template script [`apachectl.in`](https://github.com/apache/httpd/blob/trunk/support/apachectl.in).  Different releases of Apache differ of course, but one thing common to the variations of `apachectl` is that the script checks for configuration settings which can include the location of your server's modules.  In the current version of the template, that's just below a comment

```
# pick up any necessary environment variables
```

If you run `httpd-prefork` directly without setting those variables, it will not work properly.  That explains why it reported that the module was not loaded.  You might get a more informative report if you did not `grep` the output, e.g., there might be no listing at all.